# Compress-Archive, exclude the containing folder

Tags: powershell, compress-archive

I need to pack a folder using `Compress-Archive` in `PShell`

My folder structure is as following:

```sh
|- C:\MyFolder
|--- Files
|------ Start.ps1
|------ Stop.ps1
|--- Manifests
|------ Start.xml
|------ Stop.xml
```

When I issue this command `Compress-Archive -Path "C:\MyFolder" -DestinationPath "C:\MyFolder.zip"`

The result is a .zip which has a root folder called "MyFolder" while what I need is a .zip which replicate the tree of MyFolder **without** having MyFolder as the root one. Is that possible?

Answer (score 16):

The `Path` [parameter accepts specific file names and file names with wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.1#example-1--compress-files-to-create-an-archive-file). So instead of `C:\MyFolder` as `Path` parameter you could do pass `"C:\MyFolder\*`"(all its files and subdirectories *hence skipping the root directory*)

```
Compress-Archive -Path "C:\MyFolder\*" -DestinationPath "C:\MyFolder.zip"
```

This is also [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.1#parameters),

> **-Path**
>
> Specifies the path or paths to the files that you want to add to the archive zipped file. To specify multiple paths, and include files
> in multiple locations, use commas to separate the paths.
>
> This parameter accepts wildcard characters. Wildcard characters allow
> you to add all files in a directory to your archive file.
>
> Using wildcards with a root directory affects the archive's contents:
>
> To create an archive that includes the root directory, and all its
> files and subdirectories, specify the root directory in the Path
> without wildcards. For example: `-Path C:\Reference`
>
> **To create an
> archive that excludes the root directory, but zips all its files and
> subdirectories, use the asterisk (*) wildcard. For example: `-Path C:\Reference\*`**
>
> To create an archive that only zips the files in the
> root directory, use the star-dot-star (`*.*`) wildcard. Subdirectories
> of the root aren't included in the archive. For example: `-Path C:\Reference\*.*`